# PHAssetCreationRequest DNG File Name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filenames, phphotolibrary

This is a snippet from Apple's sample code ***AVCamManualExtendingAVCamtoUseManualCaptureAPI*** where the DNG data has to be temprorily written in to a file before moving to **PHPhotoLibrary**:

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^( PHAuthorizationStatus status ) {  
  if ( status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {  

  NSURL *temporaryDNGFileURL;  
  if ( self.dngPhotoData ) {  
   temporaryDNGFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld.dng", resolvedSettings.uniqueID]]];  
   [self.dngPhotoData writeToURL:temporaryDNGFileURL atomically:YES];  
  }  

  [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{  
   PHAssetCreationRequest *creationRequest = [PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset];  

   if ( self.jpegPhotoData ) {  
    [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:self.jpegPhotoData options:nil];  

    if ( temporaryDNGFileURL ) {  
     PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *companionDNGResourceOptions = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];  
     companionDNGResourceOptions.shouldMoveFile = YES;  
     [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypeAlternatePhoto fileURL:temporaryDNGFileURL options:companionDNGResourceOptions];  
    }  
   }  
   else {  
    PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *dngResourceOptions = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];  
    dngResourceOptions.shouldMoveFile = YES;  
    [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto fileURL:temporaryDNGFileURL options:dngResourceOptions];  
   }  

  } completionHandler:^( BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error ) {  
   if ( ! success ) {  
   NSLog( @"Error occurred while saving photo to photo library: %@", error );  
   }  

   if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:temporaryDNGFileURL.path] ) {  
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:temporaryDNGFileURL error:nil];  
   }  

   [self didFinish];  
  }];  
  }  
  else {  
   NSLog( @"Not authorized to save photo" );  
   [self didFinish];  
  }  
 }];
```

In above code, the line creates the DNG file name using **resolvedSettings.uniqueID**:

```
 temporaryDNGFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld.dng", resolvedSettings.uniqueID]]];
```

Above line creates a file named, for example, 23lld.dng.  This becomes a problem when users want consecutive file names along with JPEG's and other asset file names in the photo library.

If the users last asset's file name is **IMG_0155.jpg**, the DNG file being created should be **IMG_0156.dng** in this case.

How would I be able to get the proper name for the DNG file?

Notable API's I came across:

- **PHAssetResourceCreationOptions**
- **PHAssetResourceCreationOptions.originalFilename**
- **PHAssetResourceCreationOptions.uniformTypeIdentifier**
- **PHAssetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset**

Somehow I am having tying all the together to come up with a solution.

Comment: iOS photo library entries don't have user-facing names. And your code cannot reference the asset by name either. So it seems this should not really be an issue.

Comment: When you save a JPEG using [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:self.jpegPhotoData options:nil];, it saves with the proper file name.

Comment: You see, the resolvedSettings.uniqueID is to generate a tmp address for you to write to your temp folder, it then ask PhotoLibrary to save the file from provided address(in your case the tmp url).

Comment: True.  uniqueID provides a two digit number, which even repeats sometimes.  I just want to save it to default.  If last asset was IMG_9603, new one should be IMG_9604.

Comment: Were you be able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I have not.  Did a request on it.  No solution.